# How to add .gif Animation in unity Scene ? Does Unity support Animated GIFS?

Tags: android, animation, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am working on Unity + Augmented reality. I want to show some "animated .gif" file on specific location on Marker detection event.
I manage all but, I wanna display .gif animation at specific location on Android screen.
But I think

**Unity does not support .gif**

and

**Android does not support VideoTexture.**

Comment: Your best shot would be either to convert your gif to video and use the video plugin from Vuforia or EasyVideo plugin. The first is free but I have never used it, the second is a plugin that cost about €30. It is simple to use but costs. The last solution is to cut your gif into a Sprite animation (Texture atlad) and use an Animator to run the animation. I would guess your gif is not too long so that could do.

Comment: As per your last soln its same like use png images to create animation in unity

Comment: Yes it is which if your gif is not so long would not be a huge problem. On top of that, making animation with sprite takes 5min.

Comment: the simplest solution is to use 2DToolkit.  even though Unity now has a 2D system, almost all big projects still use 2DToolkit as it is just so easy for certain things.  To make an animation like you describe, is one click in 2DTK.

Answer (score 11):

Unity not support Gif.

You have 2 options:

1. Split animation and use Animator: [there you have a nice howto](http://michaelcummings.net/mathoms/creating-2d-animated-sprites-using-unity-4.3)
2. Save individual frames and make an array of textures.

   var frames : Texture[];
   var framesPerSecond = 10;

   function Update() 
   {
   var index : int = (Time.time * framesPerSecond) % frames.Length;
   renderer.material.mainTexture = frames[index];
   }

Comment: So, in short you mean to say I have to use same png images as a texture to create animation instead of using .gif

Comment: Yes, this is the option 2,a png or another image format secuency in an array of textures. For me is more friendly and sorted the option 1.